# Failed to attach the USB device - SKYMEDI USB drive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive

I try to attach a USB drive in a virtual box Ubuntu 12.04. I select Devices from the menu and then USB devices. I select the USB drive.

Error Message

> Failed to attach the USB device SKYMEDI USB Drive [0100] to the
>   virtual machine Ubuntu. USB device 'SKYMEDI USB drive ' with UUID
>   {-some big hexadecimal number-} is busy with a previous request.
>   Please try again later

```
Result Code: 
E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: 
HostUSBDevice
Interface: 
IHostUSBDevice {173b4b44-d268-4334-a00d-b6521c9a740a}
Callee: 
IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

Though it is of brand Kingston, it shows SKYMEDI USB drive. And the pen drive does not show up.

I also have another pen drive of same type and brand which runs just fine on virtual box Ubuntu.